# Policy to deny dynamic public IP configuration in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, gateway, policy

I am trying to create an Azure policy to deny the creation of application gateway if the public IP address allocation is "Dynamic".

I tried using the "publicIPAllocationMethod" as a strong type but it throws me an error.

I am seeing these fields are coming in the property and not a type.

```
   {
    "mode": "all",
    "policyRule": {
    "if": {
           "allOf": [
                    {
                       "field": "publicIPAddress",
      "equals": "dynamic"
    }
  ]
},
"then": {
  "effect": "deny"
}
   },
    "parameters": {}
  }
```

Comment: You will need to use an alias to reach the "publicIpAddress" property. See [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases)

Answer (score 0):

policy works on an aliases basis so the field must be an aliases. Upon my research, it looks like the aliases for publicIDAddress within Application Gateway is Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress.

However the value in my resource payload is an id.

The only thing that I see that can be labeled as dynamic is Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].privateIPAllocationMethod but that could just be how my resource is configured.

I would recommend seeing here on how to find aliases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases

Comment: Please try to summarize the content within any links you provide just in case they ever die out in the future. This helps maintain future readability of answers.